# Dimiss modal View Controller in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I got `View A present -> Modal View B, B present -> Modal View C  Modal View D -> Modal View E` . It's a main View **A** and then succession of Modal view.

 So each time I present new modal **C or D** I want to dismiss the previous one (In this way when I close the new presented Modal It will show me The Main view A always not the previous Modal).

- If I'm in B and I want to present C then I have to present C first
  then In background I dismiss B.
- If I'm in C and I want to present E then I present E first and then
  dismiss C in background

I've tried this code :

```
if (_openNextView) {
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"generatedCode"]) {
            NSLog(@"generated Code %@ : ", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"generatedCode"]);
            NSLog(@"phone Number %@ : ", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"phoneNumber"]);

            // Present C View
            RegisterSecondViewController *registerSecond = [[RegisterSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterSecondViewController" bundle:nil];

            //[self presentNatGeoViewController:registerSecond];

            [self presentViewController:registerSecond animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            RegisterFirstViewController *registerFirst = [[RegisterFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterFirstViewController" bundle:nil];

             //present D view
            //[self presentNatGeoViewController:registerFirst];
            [self presentViewController:registerFirst animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
// Dismiss privious View (the current view before presenting new one)
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also I've o add this code in the new presented Modal view

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But didn't worked and the view is not dismissed

Comment: Why are you using modals ?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I didn't paid attention it's registration system and it can be displayed from any View like popup ,also  in some time user can skip step but can't go back. 
do you think it's not good choice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd modally present a `UINavigationController` and use it to present the content views. Then, when you currently present new modal views instead you would just set the `viewControllers` (animated) of the navigation controller.

This will give you an animated view of progression through your setup process but won't allow the user to go back and will deallocate the VCs when they're complete.

Comment: Thank's I've tried this and also I hidded the navigationBar to make it looks as modal view, it worked as charm thank's

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` has a property named `presentedViewController` :

> presentedViewController
>   Property The view controller that is
>   presented by this view controller, or one of its ancestors in the view
>   controller hierarchy. (read-only)

This means, you can only present one modal controller at a given time. In order to present another one, you need to dismiss the current one first.

If you want to have a custom navigation, I recommend you to create a custom container view controller since the normal modal presentation won't fit your use case. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) is a guide from Apple.

Comment: I Think you miss understood me, when I present the new view modal I want to dismiss the previous one SO when I close the new Modal I will get the Main view A on my screen not the previous modal View

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the current vc after that presenting a new vc. Try this:

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
    if (self.presentingViewController != nil) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: This will dimiss the new presented view Controller